# Make QGraphicsView do smooth centerOn

Tags: qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview

i am not really newbie in Qt, but there are a few things i don't know...
I am programming in Python, but feel free to post your answers in ANY language.

So, i have a few **QGraphicsItem** (s), positioned inside a **QGraphicsScene**, the scene is viewed with a normal **QGraphicsView**. Everything is normal.

My scene is very large, 10,000 x 10,000 pixels, all graphic items are scattered around.

For example :

```
 # Creating Scene object.
 scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
 scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 10000, 10000)
 # Creating View object.
 view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
 view.setScene(scene)

 # Adding some objects to scene.
 # scene.addItem(...)
 # ...

 # The list of items.
 items = scene.items()

 # This is how i center on item.
 view.centerOn(some_item)
 view.fitInView(some_item, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

My question is, **how** can i center the view on every item, using something similar to **centerOn**, but smoothly ?

Currently, centerOn goes FAST on next item, i want to move it slooowly, maybe using **QPropertyAnimation** with easing curve ?

I tried to move the view to the next item using **view.translate(1, 1)** in a big cicle, but the movement is too fast, just like centerOn.

I tried to put some waiting with **time.sleep(0.01)** between the translating, but the windows blocks untill the cicle exists... so it's bad.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

I once used a QTimeLine (with EaseInOutCurve), connected it to a slot, and then used that value to translate the view rect, like this:

```
const QRectF r = ...calculate rect translated by timeline value and trajectory...
view->setSceneRect( r );
view->fitInView( r, Qt::KeepAspectRatio );
```

For the trajectory I used a QLineF with start and end position for the smooth scrolling.
Then one can use the value emitted by timeline nicely with QLineF::pointAt().

In my case I needed to set both SceneRect and fitInView to make it behave like I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by placing a high value on setSceneRect. Then I centralize the scene on an object or position.

example:

this->ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect (0,0,100000000, 100000000); 
this->ui->graphicsView->centerOn(500,1030);

With the setSceneRect size GraphicsView does not work right.