# How to implement a smooth QGraphicsView::centerOn(QGraphicsItem)?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qt4.8

I have a `QGraphicsItem` descendant called `lnk`, and I use this code to move the graphics view rect to its location into the scene:

```
ui->graphicsView->centerOn(lnk);
```

Now, I would like the view to scroll **smoothly** to the location of the item (like google maps for example).

Looking-up with google and stackoverflow, I found some solutions but all are based on the old API and not so clear for me.

For example, this one: [Make QGraphicsView do smooth centerOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104494/make-qgraphicsview-do-smooth-centeron) is based on old API and source code is incomplete. This one is outdated too: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30970-QGraphicsView-centerOn()-with-smooth-scrolling

Please help me to understand how I can get this with the new API (I guess that I must use QPropertyAnimation facility)?

Comment: I don't think you should use QPropertyAnimation. Is the current scroll value a property? Maybe it is, but it seems kind of weird to me. Use QTimeLine with translate. It's not out-of-date at all.

Comment: Anthony you are right, thankyou! QTimeLine is not deprecated, and I'll try to solve my proble with these.